# Can't draw inside a groupbox control in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

Its a simple and straightforward question. I couldn't draw a rectangle inside a groupbox. Any answer will be really helpful.

```
    private void groupBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        g.FillRectangle(b, 800, 70, 360, 440);
    }
```

I think there was sth wrong with my ide. I had tried Graphics g = e.Graphics before. I tried again after restarting my computer. Now its working. I think something happened to my computer or visual studio. Thanks for your support.

Comment: are you sure about `this.CreateGraphics()`?

Comment: Use `e.Graphics` instead of `this.CreateGraphics()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `this.CreateGraphics()` you have to use `e.Graphics`

Example:

```
private void groupBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(b, 800, 70, 360, 440);
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need the call to `group.Invalidate();`

Comment: `Invalidate` will call the `Paint` event, so you will reenter the handler, try it yourself.

Comment: You can get rid of `Invalidate` at all, the code without the call works fine, just put the `b` inside an `using` and done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
```

Instead of `this` statement use your *`groupBoxName`* you want to draw on, like this

```
Graphics g = groupBox.CreateGraphics();
```